# How to modify the datawindow of a dddw at runtime

Tags: powerbuilder

I need to modify the datawindow of a dropdowndatawindow dynamically.

I use `GetChild` to get the appropriate `DataWindowChild`. Then I change the font weight of the display column like this:

```
ls_error = ldwc_dddw.Modify('product_desc.font.weight="400~tIF(Trim(product_desc) = ~'AAVBF00~', 700, 400)"')
```

`ls_error` stays empty and when I check the result with `Describe()` I get the expected syntax. But the DDDW still behaves as if the `Modify()` did not happen.

Do I need to do a refresh of the DDDW? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer....

I made the change to the DDDW datawindow in the pfe_customize event. That did not work.
When I do the same change in the dropdown event it works fine.

Apparently the datawindow is reloaded sometime after pfe_customize has been executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try another 'getchild' on the dddw column after the modify

Comment: Maybe set the expression on the dddw datawindow object which looks at some column you set after your getchild?